# Python: Converting excel file to JSON format

Tags: python, json, excel, etl

I am creating a ML model that will use a JSON file to understand the pattern and response format. As I have my data in excel format I converted it to JSON in python.

Here is the code:

```
import xlrd
from collections import OrderedDict
import simplejson as json
# Open the workbook and select the first worksheet
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('D:\\android\\testdata2.xlsx')
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
# List to hold dictionaries
data_list = []
# Iterate through each row in worksheet and fetch values into dict
for rownum in range(1, sh.nrows):
    data = OrderedDict()
    row_values = sh.row_values(rownum)
    data['pattern'] = row_values[0]
    data['response'] = row_values[1]
    data_list.append(data)
# Serialize the list of dicts to JSON
j = json.dumps(data_list)
# Write to file
with open('data1.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(j)
```

I am the getting the output as:

```
[{
    "pattern": "WALLSTENT NON COUVERTE ",
    "response": "ENDOPROTHESE STENT  VASCULAIRE "
}, {
    "pattern": "PRIMEADVANCED SURSCAN MRI ",
    "response": "NEUROSTIMULATEUR NERF VAGUE GAUCHE "
}, {
    "pattern": "AVASTIN  FLACON DE",
    "response": "BEVACIZUMAB"
}, {
    "pattern": "PERJETA SOLUTION A DILUER POUR PERFUSION",
    "response": "BRENTUXIMAB VEDOTIN"
}]
```

The desired output I am looking for is like this:

```
{
    "intents": [{
        "pattern": ["WALLSTENT, NON, COUVERTE "],
        "response": ["ENDOPROTHESE STENT  VASCULAIRE] "
    }, {
        "pattern": ["PRIMEADVANCED ,SURSCAN ,MRI"] ,
        "response": ["NEUROSTIMULATEUR NERF VAGUE GAUCHE "]
    }, {
        "pattern": ["AVASTIN , FLACON ,DE"],
        "response": ["BEVACIZUMAB"]
    }, {
        "pattern": ["PERJETA, SOLUTION, A, DILUER, POUR ,PERFUSION"],
        "response": ["BRENTUXIMAB VEDOTIN"]
    }]
}
```

What modification can I do in my function to get the output I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

That should do it:

```
import xlrd
from collections import OrderedDict
import simplejson as json
# Open the workbook and select the first worksheet
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('D:\\android\\testdata2.xlsx')
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
# List to hold dictionaries
data_list = []
# Iterate through each row in worksheet and fetch values into dict
for rownum in range(1, sh.nrows):
    data = OrderedDict()
    row_values = sh.row_values(rownum)
    data['pattern'] = row_values[0]
    data['response'] = row_values[1]
    data_list.append(data)
data_list = {'intents': data_list} # Added line
# Serialize the list of dicts to JSON
j = json.dumps(data_list)
# Write to file
with open('data1.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(j)
```

Note the added `data_list = {'intents': data_list}`.

Comment: i added the line and it gives this error as i run the program.                                         "list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Comment: Apologies, I fixed it.

Comment: Note that in the python shell there needs to be a new line between data_list.append(data) and data_list = {'intents': data_list}

Answer (score 2):

Give a shot to pyexcel_xlsx library in python. I have used this for converting xlsx to json. Sweet and simple one. And fast also as compared to other python libraries.

Sample code:

```
from pyexcel_xlsx import get_data;
import time;
import json;

data = get_data("D:\\android\\testdata2.xlsx")
sheetName = "Table A";

data_list = []
# Iterate through each row and append in above list
for i in range(0, len(data[sheetName])):
    data_list.append({
        'pattern' : data[sheetName][i][0],
        'response' : data[sheetName][i][1]
    })
data_list = {'intents': data_list} # Converting to required object
j = json.dumps(data_list)
# Write to file
with open('data1.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(j)
```