# Converting Excel into JSON using Python

Tags: python, json, excel, python-3.x

I have an excel file and I want to convert it into a `JSON` file. So the excel is something like this:

```
-------------------------
| Col A | Col C | Col F |
--------+-------+--------
|   1   |   A   |   EE  |
|   2   |   B   |   FF  |
|   4   |   C   |   FF  |
|   5   |   D   |   HH  |
|   6   |   D   |   HH  |
|   7   |   A   |   EE  |
|   8   |   E   |   EE  |
--------------------------
```

I would like the `JSON` to follow this format:

```
{
"EE": {
    "A": {
      "Col A key": "1",
      "Col A key": "7"
    },
    "E": {
      "Col A key": "8"
    },
  },

"FF": {
    "B": {
      "Col A key": "2"
    },
    "C": {
      "Col A key": "4"
    }
  },

"HH": {
    "D": {
      "Col A key": "5",
      "Col A key": "6"
    }
  }

}
```

Can anyone help me implement this using `python`? I've tried various ways but without success. This is what I have done so far:

```
import openpyxl, pprint, json
print('Opening workbook...')
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('excel_form.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')


excel_data = {}
print('Reading rows...')
for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    Col F  = sheet['F' + str(row)].value
    Col C = sheet['C' + str(row)].value
    Col A = sheet['A' + str(row)].value

    excel_data.setdefault(Col F, {})
    excel_data[Col F].setdefault(Col C, {'Col A': Col A})


# Open a new text file and write the contents of excel_data to it.
print('Writing results...')
with open('DATA.json', 'w') as resultFile:
    json.dump(Matrix, resultFile)
print('Done.')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the *specific* problem with the posted code?

Comment: How about this previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53940031/python-converting-excel-file-to-json-format

Comment: Imo you should consider using the simplejson package instead of trying to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 16):

Went through a couple of solutions, this is the one that worked best for me. Hope this can save someone else some time.

```
import pandas
import json

# Read excel document
excel_data_df = pandas.read_excel('data.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1')

# Convert excel to string 
# (define orientation of document in this case from up to down)
thisisjson = excel_data_df.to_json(orient='records')

# Print out the result
print('Excel Sheet to JSON:\n', thisisjson)

# Make the string into a list to be able to input in to a JSON-file
thisisjson_dict = json.loads(thisisjson)

# Define file to write to and 'w' for write option -> json.dump() 
# defining the list to write from and file to write to
with open('data.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(thisisjson_dict, json_file)
```

Comment: NameError: name 'json' is not defined

Comment: Worked for me after I changed 'sheet1' to 'Sheet1', as in my case, the default sheet name had a capital S.  I also had to install two packages with pip3:  pandas and openpyxl.

Answer (score 10):

I prefer using `xlrd` to convert the Excel rows into a `JSON` format.

```
import xlrd
from collections import OrderedDict
import json
```

---

Open the workbook and select the first worksheet

```
wb = xlrd.open_workbook("Excel-sheet location here")
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
```

---

Create a list to hold dictionaries

```
data_list = []
```

---

Iterate through each row in worksheet and fetch values into dict

```
for rownum in range(1, sh.nrows):
     data = OrderedDict()

row_values = sh.row_values(rownum)
data['<Column Name1>'] = row_values[0]
data['<Column Name2>'] = row_values[1]
data_list.append(data)
```

---

Write to file:

```
 with open("RulesJson.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as writeJsonfile:
      json.dump(data_list, writeJsonfile, indent=4,default=str)
```

Answer (score 6):

There are **2 approaches** for achieving the result:

1. Using `excel2json`. It's quite a simple tool but might be helpful for you.

   - First, install the package `excel2json-3` using `pip`.
   - Then, running this code block should output a `JSON` file for each sheet in the file:

```
import excel2json

excel2json.convert_from_file('excel_form.xlsx')
```

---

2. Using `pandas`. If you are looking for a more comprehensive solution, you might as well find `pandas` useful. It is a library made for data manipulation and has many more features.

   - First install `pandas` via `pip`.
   - Then, running this code should result with printing a `JSON` string describing the excel sheet called `Sheet`.

```
import pandas

excel_data_fragment = pandas.read_excel('excel_form.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet')

json_str = excel_data_fragment.to_json()

print('Excel Sheet to JSON:\n', json_str)
```

[Link to the source](https://www.journaldev.com/33335/python-excel-to-json-conversion)

Comment: It thows **AttributeError: module 'excel2json' has no attribute 'convert_from_file'** error

Comment: `pandas` is a bit of overkill if you just want to read in the data. if you want to transform the data in some way that leverages `pandas`, then that would be more ideal.

Comment: Note that excel2json has been unmaintained since 2018.