# json from three rows of an Excel

Tags: python, json, excel

I have an excel sheet that has three rows with two headings in the first row. The cell containing the first heading is the merged cell of three cells, and 2nd heading is the merged cell of two (as shown in the attached picture). The 2nd row contains another set of the headings and the third row has the values.

[image].

I would like to create a JSON form these three rows and it should look like the following

```
{
    "H1": [
        "h11": 10,
        "h12": 20,
        "h13": 30
    ],
    "H2": [
        "h21": 40,
        "h22": 50,
    ],
}
```

I am currently manually retrieving cell values from excel using `pyoo` or `panda` library and making the JSON. I am wondering if there is an easier way to do that.

Comment: Hello @SBDK8219, you may find this thread helpful: [Converting Excel into JSON using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60044233/converting-excel-into-json-using-python).

Comment: @AvivYaniv yes, it looks similar to my problem. I will try changing rows to columns.

Comment: @AvivYaniv, I tried with different combinations of rows and columns, but both `excel2json.convert_from_file` and `panda` did not produce desired result