# How to convert Excel file into a Json file to send as request into an api python

Tags: python, json, api

I have an excel spreadsheet, which contains 5 columns and 30 rows. All column and row information are already filled in. What I would like to do is take this worksheet and send a request to an api to make, for example, a product registration. This product registration within the API would be according to the column and row names. How could I do this in python?

EDIT:

To make requests in this api:

```
url = "https://myurl/api/catalog/pvt/product"

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "API-AppKey": "MYKEY",
    "API-AppToken": "MYTOKEN"
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payloads)
response = response.json()
```

In my excel file, column A is column Name. Column B is the Category column, price column C.. and so on.

Comment: If you open up your excel sheet using pandas, you can use the `df.to_json()` method to dump it into json format.

Comment: Welcome to SO, there are quite a few details missing here. How do you send the data to the API? - can you include some documentation or an example? How is your Excel file formatted exactly (what row is what)? - Can you include an example please?

Comment: you can refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67001137/12410821

Comment: thank you, @Dev! I managed to convert! but.. and to send this json file to my api? how would i do? sorry if the questions are confusing, i'm new to programming.

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan I made some edits in The question