# convert excel to json file in python

Tags: python, json, excel, dataframe

I am new here , need some help with writing to json file:

I have a dataframe with below values, which is created by reading a excel file
[image]

need to write this to json file with object as column dtls

Output :

[image]

Comment: If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here with your code.

Comment: Show JSON and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Answer (score 0):

I hope, it works for your solution.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
df = pd.read_excel('./TfidfVectorizer_sklearn.xlsx')
df.to_json('new_file1.json', orient='records') # excel to json
# read json and then append details to it
with open('./new_file1.json', 'r') as json_file: 
    a = {}
    data = json.load(json_file)
    a['details'] = data
# write new json with details in it
with open("./new_file1.json", "w") as jsonFile:
    json.dump(a, jsonFile)
```

**JSON Output:**

[image]

Comment: i am not able to get an object name in the output .for example "Details" is missing in the final output

Comment: Kindly look at my updated code

Answer (score 0):

A similar task is considered in the question:

[Converting Excel into JSON using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60044233/converting-excel-into-json-using-python)

Different approaches are possible to solve this problem.